# Application settings aren't begin deleted when I uninstall my program

Tags: c#, uninstallation, application-settings

My code is using Application Settings in order to save some configs for the user, but when I uninstall my program and then re-install it! All the previous configs are still there!!!! and it's driving me crazy! Does anyone by any chance know what's happening?
I have also read this in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769544%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), but no help!

> If an application is uninstalled, the data root and everything within the store, including the isolated storage folder, is deleted.

Comment: This *is* weird! Make and model of the device?

Comment: My code is running on Win-7 I have also checked that on windows xp on my VMWare still the same result!!!!!!!!

Comment: you mean you are running it on simulator?

Comment: No I meant, I have also tested it on Simulator but still not working

Comment: Is this on an actual device or in the emulator? And yes it may seem like a silly question but exactly how are you uninstalling the app?

Comment: From the Control Panel->uninstall a program, and it will be uninstalled:D

Comment: Removed Windows Phone 7 tag.  Control Panel | Uninstall.... Not in Windows Phone.